# Developement of modern condensed matter physics

Tags: condensed-matter, history

Do you know any resources describing historical aspects of developments of modern condensed matter physics (many body physics etc)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I found [Essay: Fifty Years of Condensed Matter Physics (December 16, 2008)](http://prl.aps.org/edannounce/PhysRevLett.101.250001)

written by Marvin L. Cohen, I'm sure you could find more articles on bases like Scopus, Scirus etc.

Also did you tried googling 'Review of Condensed Matter Physics'? Maybe something will come up.

Comment: Thanks, Im sure its a helpful link. I still search for more detailed one especially on main mathematical steps and contributions of different people.

Comment: I see. I don't think that there is a paper really about this (I hope I'm wrong because that would be really cool), you could follow this list: http://www.physik.uni-kl.de/eggert/festkoerper/history.pdf and look past QED development era, and try searching one by one, that would be the safest, yet longer, route. I wish you all the luck in your search :)